# How can I use React with Google Places API, to display place markers on a Google map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, react-google-maps

I'm trying to build a similar map as [on Airbnb](https://www.airbnb.com/s/San-Francisco--CA--United-States/homes?place_id=ChIJIQBpAG2ahYAR_6128GcTUEo&refinement_path=%2Fhomes&allow_override%5B%5D=&s_tag=eznNGZGg), where you can view place markers as you drag the map around. **I would like to display "hotel" markers from the Google Places API on a map.**

Using the following JavaScript code from [Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search), I can display hotels on the Google map, but I would like to do this with React, using [react-google-maps](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Place searches</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
      // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
      // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

      var map;
      var infowindow;

      function initMap() {
        var pyrmont = {lat: -33.867, lng: 151.195};

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: pyrmont,
          zoom: 15
        });

        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        service.nearbySearch({
          location: pyrmont,
          radius: 500,
          type: ['hotel']
        }, callback);
      }

      function callback(results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            createMarker(results[i]);
          }
        }
      }

      function createMarker(place) {
        var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: place.geometry.location
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.setContent(place.name);
          infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[react-google-maps](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#searchbox) has an example of showing the search input field. So with that I'm able to search and show markers by searching, e.g., "hotels in London". But instead of searching for places, I would like to immediately show the markers for hotels. (The API key in the example below is from the react-google-maps example.)

```
const _ = require("lodash");
const { compose, withProps, lifecycle } = require("recompose");
const {
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  Marker,
} = require("react-google-maps");
const { SearchBox } = require("react-google-maps/lib/components/places/SearchBox");

const MapWithASearchBox = compose(
  withProps({
    googleMapURL: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC4R6AN7SmujjPUIGKdyao2Kqitzr1kiRg&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places",
    loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    containerElement: <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />,
    mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
  }),
  lifecycle({
    componentWillMount() {
      const refs = {}

      this.setState({
        bounds: null,
        center: {
          lat: 41.9, lng: -87.624
        },
        markers: [],
        onMapMounted: ref => {
          refs.map = ref;
        },
        onBoundsChanged: () => {
          this.setState({
            bounds: refs.map.getBounds(),
            center: refs.map.getCenter(),
          })
        },
        onSearchBoxMounted: ref => {
          refs.searchBox = ref;
        },
        onPlacesChanged: () => {
          const places = refs.searchBox.getPlaces();
          const bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

          places.forEach(place => {
            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
              bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport)
            } else {
              bounds.extend(place.geometry.location)
            }
          });
          const nextMarkers = places.map(place => ({
            position: place.geometry.location,
          }));
          const nextCenter = _.get(nextMarkers, '0.position', this.state.center);

          this.setState({
            center: nextCenter,
            markers: nextMarkers,
          });
          // refs.map.fitBounds(bounds);
        },
      })
    },
  }),
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap
)(props =>
  <GoogleMap
    ref={props.onMapMounted}
    defaultZoom={15}
    center={props.center}
    onBoundsChanged={props.onBoundsChanged}
  >
    <SearchBox
      ref={props.onSearchBoxMounted}
      bounds={props.bounds}
      controlPosition={google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT}
      onPlacesChanged={props.onPlacesChanged}
    >
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Customized your placeholder"
        style={{
          boxSizing: `border-box`,
          border: `1px solid transparent`,
          width: `240px`,
          height: `32px`,
          marginTop: `27px`,
          padding: `0 12px`,
          borderRadius: `3px`,
          boxShadow: `0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)`,
          fontSize: `14px`,
          outline: `none`,
          textOverflow: `ellipses`,
        }}
      />
    </SearchBox>
    {props.markers.map((marker, index) =>
      <Marker key={index} position={marker.position} />
    )}
  </GoogleMap>
);

<MapWithASearchBox />
```

I have been trying to figure this out for many days now, and have been looking for tutorials, but I couldn't find a solution. I understand that I should use:

```
new google.maps.places.PlacesService()
```

And add options:

```
 const center = new google.maps.LatLng(37.422, -122.084068);
 const options = {
   location: center
   radius: '500',
   types: ['hotel']
 };
```

And when using the react-google-maps, I need to use the *withScriptjs*. But how do I put all of this together?

**How can I use react-google-maps with [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search), to display "hotel" markers from Google on the map?**

[image: Hotel markers on google map]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do that by passing a ref of your `GoogleMap` to `new google.maps.places.PlacesService()` to create a service and then with that service you can use `nearbySearch()` to search for hotels, restaurants, etc. As the [Google Places Nearby Search API docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests) says:

> A Nearby Search lets you search for places within a specified area by keyword or type.

To fire the `fetchPlaces()` method you can use both `onTilesLoaded` prop from [GoogleMap](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#googlemap) component or `componentDidMount()`. In the example below I also passed `fetchPlaces` to `onBoundChanged` since I am basing my search on `bounds` so it can give me new places every time I move the map, note here:

```
const bounds = refs.map.getBounds();
const service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(refs.map.context.__SECRET_MAP_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED);
const request = {
  bounds: bounds,
  type: ['hotel']
};
```

Here is my example using `recompose`:

```
/*global google*/
import React from "react"
import { compose, withProps, withHandlers, withState } from "recompose"
import { withScriptjs, withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Marker } from "react-google-maps"

const MyMapComponent = compose(
    withProps({
        googleMapURL: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places",
        loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
        containerElement: <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />,
        mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    }),
    withScriptjs,
    withGoogleMap,
    withState('places', 'updatePlaces', ''),
    withHandlers(() => {
        const refs = {
            map: undefined,
        }

        return {
            onMapMounted: () => ref => {
                refs.map = ref
            },
            fetchPlaces: ({ updatePlaces }) => {
                let places;
                const bounds = refs.map.getBounds();
                const service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(refs.map.context.__SECRET_MAP_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED);
                const request = {
                    bounds: bounds,
                    type: ['hotel']
                };
                service.nearbySearch(request, (results, status) => {
                    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                        console.log(results);
                        updatePlaces(results);
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }),
)((props) => {
    return (
        <GoogleMap
            onTilesLoaded={props.fetchPlaces}
            ref={props.onMapMounted}
            onBoundsChanged={props.fetchPlaces}
            defaultZoom={8}
            defaultCenter={{ lat: 51.508530, lng: -0.076132 }}
        >
            {props.places && props.places.map((place, i) =>
                <Marker key={i} position={{ lat: place.geometry.location.lat(), lng: place.geometry.location.lng() }} />
            )}
        </GoogleMap>
    )
})

export default class MyFancyComponent extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        return (
            <MyMapComponent />
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Tiago, I have another related question, that you might know the answer to? :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47205165/when-displaying-multiple-markers-on-a-map-how-to-open-just-one-info-window-whe