# When displaying multiple markers on a map, how to open just one info window, when clicking on a marker?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, react-google-maps

I'm using [react-google-maps](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps) to display a map with markers, and when you click on a marker, all the info windows open up. I would like to display only one marker's info window when I click on it, and for the others to stay closed.

Here is my code:

```
    <GoogleMap
        defaultZoom={15}
        defaultCenter={{ lat: 51.508530, lng: -0.076132 }}
    >
        {props.places && props.places.map((place, i) =>
            <Marker onClick={props.onToggleOpen} key={i} position={{ lat: place.geometry.location.lat(), lng: place.geometry.location.lng() }} >
                {props.isOpen && <InfoWindow onCloseClick={props.onToggleOpen}>
                  <div>{place.name}</div>
                </InfoWindow>}
            </Marker>
        )}
    </GoogleMap>
```

And I'm opening and closing the InfoWindow with this

```
import { compose, withProps, withStateHandlers, withHandlers, withState } from "recompose";

...

withStateHandlers(() => ({
  isOpen: false,
}), {
  onToggleOpen: ({ isOpen, id }) => () => ({
    isOpen: !isOpen,
  })
}),
```

I'm mapping over all the markers, and displaying them on the map. How could I click open just one marker InfoWindow? 
[Here is a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875596/have-just-one-infowindow-open-in-google-maps-api-v3), but it's not made with React, and doesn't use the react-google-maps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's more of a `React` question. You can pass the index of a clicked `Marker` to `onToggleOpen` and instead of `isOpen` you use a `selectedPlace` state that holds the index of a clicked `Marker` and use this index to render the right `InfoWindow`.

Here is an example (not fully tested, but you can get the idea):

```
/*global google*/
import React from "react"
import { compose, withProps, withHandlers, withState, withStateHandlers } from "recompose"
import { withScriptjs, withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Marker, InfoWindow } from "react-google-maps"

const MyMapComponent = compose(
    withProps({
        googleMapURL: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places",
        loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
        containerElement: <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />,
        mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    }),
    withScriptjs,
    withGoogleMap,
    withState('places', 'updatePlaces', ''),
    withState('selectedPlace', 'updateSelectedPlace', null),
    withHandlers(() => {
        const refs = {
            map: undefined,
        }

        return {
            onMapMounted: () => ref => {
                refs.map = ref
            },
            fetchPlaces: ({ updatePlaces }) => {
                let places;
                const bounds = refs.map.getBounds();
                const service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(refs.map.context.__SECRET_MAP_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED);
                const request = {
                    bounds: bounds,
                    type: ['hotel']
                };
                service.nearbySearch(request, (results, status) => {
                    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                        console.log(results);
                        updatePlaces(results);
                    }
                })
            },
            onToggleOpen: ({ updateSelectedPlace }) => key => {
                updateSelectedPlace(key);
            }
        }
    }),
)((props) => {
    console.log(props);
    return (
        <GoogleMap
            onTilesLoaded={props.fetchPlaces}
            ref={props.onMapMounted}
            onBoundsChanged={props.fetchPlaces}
            defaultZoom={15}
            defaultCenter={{ lat: 51.508530, lng: -0.076132 }}
        >
            {props.places && props.places.map((place, i) =>
                <Marker onClick={() => props.onToggleOpen(i)} key={i} position={{ lat: place.geometry.location.lat(), lng: place.geometry.location.lng() }}>
                    {props.selectedPlace === i && <InfoWindow onCloseClick={props.onToggleOpen}>
                        <div>
                            {props.places[props.selectedPlace].name}
                        </div>
                    </InfoWindow>}
                </Marker>
            )}
        </GoogleMap>
    )
})

export default class MyFancyComponent extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        return (
            <MyMapComponent />
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I toggle the true / false state of whether the InfoWindow is open or not?

Comment: You use `selectedPlace` to control this. Basically, if it's `null` there is no `InfoWindow` open and if it is not null it means that there is a `infoWindow` open, that you should populate with information about a place where index is equal `selectedPlace`.

Comment: Getting lots of console errors with this, when loading the map. For example problem with withHandlers. I wonder why?